# Postfix: Delete specific emails

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm using Postfix as an email relay between a windows app that can't authenticate with gmail and gmail.

Every night between 12 and 1am this windows app sends a superfluous email that ideally I'd nuke before it gets sent.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. What did you try? Is there a reason you cannot do this with only `header_checks`?

Comment: hiya - no, there probably isn't a reason, I'm just totally, totally green at this.  I'd done some Googling and header_checks never came up once! :-D I'll go read some documentation. Thanks